# executing shell command to check file or dir exists not working in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to check if the file or directory exists before deleting it from the remote server (using net-ssh gem to connect to remote server). But the condition `[ -f #{path}/#{name} ] || [ -d #{path}/#{name} ]`is returning `nil`. `echo $?` is always returning `0` even if the file/directory does not exist.

I know that it should be simple and I spent a lot of time on this but could not make it work. Can somebody help me with this?

```
def del(path, name)
        @cond = "[ -f #{path}/#{name} ] || [ -d #{path}/#{name} ]"
        @check = "echo $?"
        @rm_cmd = "rm -rf #{file_or_dir}"

        begin
             res = @ssh.exec!(@cond)
             puts res # returns nil
             ret = @ssh.exec!(@check)
             puts ret # returns 0

             if ret.to_i == 0
                res = @ssh.exec!(@rm_cmd)
             end

             rescue
                 puts "\t#{file_or_dir} does not exist...".capitalize.red

      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are executing three shells with ssh.exec!.  Have you tried the condition and the check at the same time:

```
ret = @ssh.exec!("sh -c '[ -f #{path}/#{name} ] || [ -d #{path}/#{name} ]; echo $?'")
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was opening 3-different sessions and that is why I was having the problem. I tried giving the condition and the checking the exit status at the same time and it worked. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a shell script to do this when Ruby can do it already using the methods in [File](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html) and [FileStat](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File/Stat.html).

> File::Stat
>
> Objects of class File::Stat encapsulate common status information for File objects. The information is recorded at the moment the File::Stat object is created; changes made to the file after that point will not be reflected. File::Stat objects are returned by IO#stat, File::stat, File#lstat, and File::lstat. Many of these methods return platform-specific values, and not all values are meaningful on all systems. See also Kernel#test.

File includes FileStat, so you can use all FileStat's methods conveniently. See [`file?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-file-3F) and [`dir?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-directory-3F) to determine if something exists and is a file or a directory respectively. If you are only trying to figure out whether something exists, use [`exist?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-exist-3F).

Comment: I know that but since I have other methods where I need to run the shell commands on remote server I don't want to use Ruby File class methods.